# Ionic error: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

For the last couple of days i am trying to build and android apk file using Ionic3, Cordova and Firebase. As i am quite new to ionic i am following a specific tutorial found online that is also providing me the source code as well. The link of the tutorial is the following :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wU9N7VxoS8&t=1s and is about sending push notifications to specific devices. I follow the tutorial step by step and it seems to work fine but when i am trying to build an apk file in order to run it on my android device i ma getting the following error:

```
(node:18268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
(node:18268) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have searched and tried different methods in order to fix the bug but none of them seems to works. Can anyone please provide me with a solution?Thanks

Comment: try removing fcm plugin then platforms and once again add fcm plugin then add platforms. hopefully this helps

Comment: I removed the plugin and then the platforms, I then add the plugin again so far so good, then i add the android platform and i get the same error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
(node:15772) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."           The same goes when i try to build the android apk as well

Answer (score 2):

I resolve with:

- ionic platform rm android
- ionic platform rm ios
- ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
- ionic platform add android
- ionic platform add ios
- ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase

**Here is Github [link](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/213)**

**Ionic 3**

- ionic cordova platform rm android
- ionic cordova platform rm ios
- ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
- ionic cordova platform add android
- ionic cordova platform add ios
- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Remove default added ios platform when creating Ionic 2 app then add again. And also remove and add "cordova-fcm-plugin".
ionic platform rm ios
ionic platform add ios